# Windows batch file - automatic answer while executing batchfile through CMD prompt

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, scripting, windows-scripting

I need to suppress the auto answer to execute a batch file in CMD.

I have tried below script, but it is asking repeatedly the same

```
Echo y|D:\test\abc.bat
```

**Output:**

[image]

What can I try to resolve this issue?

Comment: This is impossible to answer without knowing the contents of `D:\test\abc.bat`

Comment: What executable is generating the prompt? Or is it the script itself?

Answer (score 0):

Use this to do that:

```
<nul set /p="y" | D:\Test\abc.bat
```

Echo was doing this with extra line break. This inserts y without any line break.